# параметры startAngle и spanAngle в методе drawChord Qt

Tags: qt, рисование

Мне нужно нарисовать круг, примерно, как на рисунке (что-бы круг был нарисован на 3/4 и что-бы хорда был параллельна оси Х):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую метод drawChord(), со стартовым углом 315 и конечным углом 225:

```
int startAngle = 315 * 16; 
int spanAngle = 225 * 16;
painter.drawChord(QRect(10, 10, 100, 100), startAngle, spanAngle);
```

И получаю, что хорда не параллельна оси X

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверное, я не правильно понимаю значение параметров startAngle, spanAngle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spanAngle` - это не конечный угол, а угол раскрыва дуги. В данном случае должно быть 270 градусов